# Can't access updated redux-state from callback in react-native (Geolocation.watchPosition)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, geolocation

i have a problem with my react-native app and would really appreciate sine help

isNavigating, route and instructions are all in my redux store. When i print them in the code below they allways have their initial value, instead of the updated value. It works fine in other functions in the same component, and other components. Anyone know why i have this problem and how to solve it?

```
     const watch = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        console.log(isNavigating)
        console.log(route)
        console.log(instructions)
        watchPositionCallback(position.coords);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.code, error.message);
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000, distanceFilter: 1, fastestInterval: 100, interval: 200 }
    );
```

I still don't really understand why, but the redux state for functions called from that callback seems to have been the same as when the callback was declared.

What i did to solve it:

```
const watch = Geolocation.watchPosition(
       watchPositionCallback,
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.code, error.message);
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000, distanceFilter: 1, fastestInterval: 100, interval: 200 }
    );

     const watchPositionCallback = (position) => {
      const locationData = {
        ....
      }
      //at first i called onLocationUpdate from here instead of setting state variable
      setLocationData(locationData);
   }

  //instead calling it from this useEffect when data updates
  useEffect(() => {
    onLocationUpdate(locationData);
  }, [locationData])
```

Comment: To update the redux-state, You'll have to dispatch action. Are you doing so ? the code snippet you shared seems you're not dispatching any action, not sure if you are doing so in `watchPositionCallback` method.

If you're updating the states using action dispatching then please appropriate way to use redux state.

Comment: Look like an issue of clouse, Can you share how you access isNavigating, route, instructions?